# When merging videos using ffmpeg videos get stuck at joint

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am using FFmpeg to join a bunch of videos in a folder
All  are videos of same type
I have using

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i file_list.txt -codec copy out.mp4
```

and also tried to reencode

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c:v libx264 -c:a libvorbis out.mp4
```

and also this

```
ffmpeg -f concat safe 0 -i file_list.txt -c copy out.mp4
```

All of them are resulting in the same issue video getting stuck at the joint for about 1 min for each clip and the audio keeps playing on,
I have downloaded the videos from Reddit using youtube-dl and changed the aspect ratio to be 16:9

```
ffmpeg -i $f -lavfi '[0:v]scale=ih*16/9:-1,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/20:luma_power=1:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/20:chroma_power=1[bg];[bg][0:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,crop=h=iw*9/16' -vb 800k fix/$f;
```

I have noticed the videos have a different bit-rate
I still don't know what's wrong I don't have much experience with FFmpeg so please if someone can help me
I am using Mac M1 Air